# Add an item in sqlquery result list

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, list

I'm calling a stored procedure using a controller.

```
var insert_query = entities.Database.SqlQuery<Call_Info>("exec [dbo].[insert_call_info] @call_id, @user_id, @call_arrive, @call_end, @info",
                        new SqlParameter("call_id", call_id),
                        new SqlParameter("user_id", u_id),
                        new SqlParameter("call_arrive", call_arrive),
                        new SqlParameter("call_end", call_end),
                        new SqlParameter("info", info)
                        ).ToList();
jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(insert_query); // <-- using Newtonsoft.Json
```

Is there a way to add `{'StatusCode':1}` in the insert_query list or to the jsonResult?

My current json string is:

```
"{\"call_info_id\":5,\"call_id\":91391,\"user_id\":\"105bdbfb-d65a-42d3-ac79-c1e2575ed243\",\"call_arrive\":\"2020-04-03T21:51:24.797\",\"call_end\":\"2020-04-03T22:04:24.797\",\"info\":\"test\",\"AspNetUser\":null,\"Call\":null}"
```

The new json string should be:

```
"{\"call_info_id\":5,\"call_id\":91391,\"user_id\":\"105bdbfb-d65a-42d3-ac79-c1e2575ed243\",\"call_arrive\":\"2020-04-03T21:51:24.797\",\"call_end\":\"2020-04-03T22:04:24.797\",\"info\":\"test\",\"AspNetUser\":null,\"Call\":null, \"StatusCode\":1}"
```

Comment: please update question with sample json output. What you have and what you want.

Comment: right now, you're probably getting a JSON array, yes? (i.e. `[ {...}, {...} ]`) so: where would the status code *go*? do you have an example output that you're after?

Comment: @MarcGravell I've added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
var insert_query = entities.Database.SqlQuery<Call_Info>("exec [dbo].[insert_call_info] @call_id, @user_id, @call_arrive, @call_end, @info",
                        new SqlParameter("call_id", call_id),
                        new SqlParameter("user_id", u_id),
                        new SqlParameter("call_arrive", call_arrive),
                        new SqlParameter("call_end", call_end),
                        new SqlParameter("info", info))
.Select(x => new {
   // Write all the properties that you want from the result
   x.call_info_id,
   x.call_id,
   x.user_id,
   x.call_arrive,
   x.call_end,
   x.info,
   x.AspNetUser,
   x.Call,
   // add the extra field 
   StausCode = 1
})
.ToList();
```

Or:

```
foreach(JObject obj in (jsonResult as JArray))
{
   obj["StatusCode"] = 1;
}
```

Or, if you can, it might be easiest to add a property to the class `Call_Info`

```
public int SatusCode => 1;
```